# In python why does raising the same exception take more memory than throwing a new exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I was profiling some code that raises exceptions to determine which of two approaches was better when I came across some memory usage that seems counter intuitive. Perhaps someone can shed some light. Test1 below raises a new exception 10K times. It takes less memory than raising the same exception 10K times. ???

Python 3.9

```
from memory_profiler import profile

TEST_COUNT = 10000


class ApplicationException(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        self.code = 0

@profile
def test1():
    for x in range(TEST_COUNT):
        try:
            raise ApplicationException()
        except:
            pass


@profile
def test2():
    application_exception = ApplicationException()
    for x in range(TEST_COUNT):
        try:
            raise application_exception
        except:
            pass


test1()
test2()
```

The results were:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
_____________________________________________________________
    10     14.1 MiB     14.1 MiB           1   @profile
    11                                         def test1():
    12     14.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       10001       for x in range(TEST_COUNT):
    13     14.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       10000           try:
    14     14.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       10000               raise ApplicationException()
    15     14.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       10000           except:
    16     14.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       10000               pass
```

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
_____________________________________________________________
    19     14.2 MiB     14.2 MiB           1   @profile
    20                                         def test2():
    21     14.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       application_exception = ApplicationException()
    22     14.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       10001       for x in range(TEST_COUNT):
    23     14.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       10000           try:
    24     14.7 MiB      0.5 MiB       10000               raise application_exception
    25     14.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       10000           except:
    26     14.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       10000               pass
```

Not sure what is going on here. Line 24 incurs some expense in memory. Can someone explain?

Comment: Have you tried running `test2` before `test1`? I suspect you are measuring the total amount of memory your process uses, not how much each individual function uses. Reverse the order of the tests, and I suspect you'll see identical results.

Comment: The report is weird, but also happens on my system (MacOS 10.14.6, Python 3.9.5). The increment actually happens on the line ``application_exception = ...``, but is reported later on. That ``application_exception = ...`` *does* take memory should be expected, since you are storing a new object here.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi If I increase the test count, the memory usage increment of line 24 increases. (MacOS 11.3.1, Python 3.9.1), so not sure if it is happening with the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In the first test, you are raising a new instance of **ApplicationException** class but *you don't assign it any variable*.

However in the second test, you assign a **ApplicationException** instance to a *variable*, than raise it. Assigned variables has extra information like name and so on. ***So, it uses more memory.***

Comment: It seems weird that what you describe would incur such a hefty memory increase. In CPython, locals are stored in an array of pointers that lives on the frame – an extra name should just be 8 more bytes that are allocated from the moment the function is called, not 500kB when raising. (There is apparently even an optimisation that caches one frame on the code object, so no new frame/locals might be created in this case.)

Comment: I just checked and the memory increase is directly proportional to the number of times the loop runs. I was thinking there might be some kind of marshaling happening between the context outside the loop and that of the loop. I don't know enough python internals to say.

Comment: Another thought I had was that the raise call would add some stack trace information which for an already raised exception instance would cause something new to be added. Again don't know enough to say.